# SVG image is not rendering using html2canvas

Tags: angular, html2canvas

I have an Angular app, and I want to screenshot a div using `html2canvas` library. But when I try to use it, image is not rendering in the created canvas/image.

Divs, svg itself, lines and other svg elements are rendering correctly, but image element is not rendering. I am keeping images in the same server, so CORS is not my problem. My simplified code is like this:

**component.html**

```
<div #ss class="image-panel">
    <div class="title">Image Title</div>
    
    <div class="main-section">
        <svg:svg width="1024" height="768">
            <image x="0" y="0" width="1024" height="768" href="IMAGE_URL"></image>
            <line x1="200" y1="200" x2="600" y2="200" stroke-width="2" stroke="red"></line>
        </svg:svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('ss') ssBase: ElementRef;

takeScreenshot() {
    html2canvas(this.ssBase.nativeElement, { useCORS: true, allowTaint: true, scale: 1 }).then(canvas => {
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
        link.download = "test.png";
        link.click();
    });
}
```